# PHP file_get_contents fails to read zip on windows

Tags: php, permissions

I've searched all over for a solution to this and I can't find one.

I'm doing something like the following:

```
$data = file_get_contents('zip://../files/' . $this->_file->getHash() . '.zip#' . $stat['name']);
```

The specific error is:

```
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

It works on a Linux machine I use, but I'm trying to get the project running on a  Windows box. I know that the path to the zip file is correct and it is readable because in the same code that the above snippet is located in, I read it using the ZipArchive class, like this:

```
$this->_za = new ZipArchive();
$res = $this->_za->open('../files/' . $file->getHash() . '.zip');
```

And that works perfectly fine.

Why can't file_get_contents read from the zip? Is there something I have to do to the files directory? I'm not very good at folders and permissions on Windows.

**Edit:** to be absolute sure it wasn't an issue with my code, I set up a very simple test script, with a zip file in the exact same directory:

```
<?php

$za = new ZipArchive();
$res = $za->open('myZip.zip');

for($i=0; $i<$za->numFiles; $i++)
{
    $stat = $za->statIndex($i);
    $data = file_get_contents('zip://myZip.zip#' . $stat['name']);

    echo $stat['name'];
    echo $data;
}
```

This outputs the name of each file in the zip (from the echo $stat['name'] part) but then produces the exact same error as before, i.e.,

```
 failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was reasonably simple. Instead of:

```
$data = file_get_contents('zip://myZip.zip#' . $stat['name']);
```

If I do:

```
$data = file_get_contents('zip://' . realpath('myZip.zip') . '#' . $stat['name']);
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the zip wrapper needs to be compiled with PHP in order to use `zip://` which appears to be the case for you.

On Windows you need to enable `php_zip.dll` inside of `php.ini` in order to use it, and may need to install a PECL extension (not sure) http://pecl.php.net/package/zip.

Comment: I'm using php 5.5, my understanding is that it's compiled in, but I will give the dll a try.

Comment: According to this it zlib is built in on Windows: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Comment: Checking the output of phpinfo() shows me that zip is enabled and registered as a stream. So it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are storing the files, but this bug on PHP might be relevant to your issue https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54128